# Add Email address in to field of Email App using share contract?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am creating a sample Win8 app and using share contract I am trying to share HTML Content. When the user select email app from the share application option I want to set email address in `TO` field. How can I do so? Following is my code written to share HTML content:

Code:

```
DataPackage requestData = request.Data;
requestData.Properties.Title = this.PageViewModel.JobInformationDetail.JobNumber;
requestData.Properties.Description = this.PageViewModel.JobInformationDetail.CustomerSignatureName;
//requestData.SetText("Sample Text");
StorageFile signatureStream = await GetInkManagerStream();
requestData.SetHtmlFormat(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.HtmlFormatHelper.CreateHtmlFormat(this.GetMailDescription()));
```

Following images shows where to set the email address in To field:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. We'll have a solution to this until WinRT come up with a standard email `DataPackage` format to [StandardDataFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats.aspx) and support it in the email app.

I think Microsoft's default Mail should be upgraded. It's entirely depend upon sharing target app to show particular data to particular place. DataPackage's `Title` property is set as subject and `Description` property is set as mail body but there's no provsion for to email(s).

If sharing experience is best one then user will user default Mail app otherwise they will go for another mail apps.